# Scala - Function's implicit return type

Tags: scala

I am new to scala, and got a little doubt about function definition & default return type.

Here is a function definition:

`def wol(s: String) = s.length.toString.length`

The prompt says it's:

> wol: (s: String)Int

But, the code didn't specify return type explicitly, shouldn't it default to `Unit`, which means `void` in Java.

So, what is the rules for default return type of a Scala function?

Comment: If you don't specify the type, it will take the type of the expression that is being returned. That's an `Int` here (because that is the declared type of `String#length`).

Comment: @Thilo But, I didn't explicitly return a value, would it take the last expression by default?

Comment: In a *block* the last expression becomes the value of the block. But you don't even have a block here, just a single expression.

Comment: Just a small note: what you have there is a *method* (exactly like a method in Java), not a *function*. Methods and functions are very different. They are distinct entities in Scala (although unfortunately, the Scala Language Specification sometimes uses the term "function" to refer to methods).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Didn't notice that before, would check more about the differences, thanks for tip.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Do you have link to the differences between a function and a method? How does one declare a function?

Comment: @Thilo: Methods can be generic, functions can't. Methods can have 0 or more parameter lists, functions always have exactly 1. Methods can have optional parameters with default arguments, functions can't. Methods can have repeated parameters, functions can't. methods can have an implicit parameter list, functions can't. Methods have a name, functions don't. Now, you might think why have functions at all, if they are worse than methods in every respect? Well, there is one very important thing: functions are objects, methods aren't (methods *belong to* objects). You can store a function in a …

Comment: … variable or a data structure, you can return a function from a method or a function, you can pass a function to a method, a function, or a constructor, you can create functions at runtime. You can do none of those things with methods. Scala is an object-oriented language, everything is done with objects; if something is not an object, that is a *serious* restriction. Functions are created using function literal syntax, e.g. `(a: Int, b: Int) => a + b` is a function. You can also use placeholder syntax, e.g. in a context where the types of the two parameters are known, you could for example …

Comment: … create the same function like this: `_ + _`. Methods, OTOH, are declared with the `def` keyword. It is also possible to create a function from a method using η-expansion, e.g.: `println _` will convert the `println` method into a function. In some cases, Scala will perform this η-expansion implicitly, for example, you can write `someList.foreach(println)`, and Scala will automatically η-expand `println` as if you had written `someList.foreach(println _)` (which after η-expansion is roughly the same as `someList.foreach(element => println(element))`). The result of η-expansion is called a …

Comment: … *partially applied method* or *partially applied function* (not to be confused with a *partial function* or a `PartialFunction`).

Comment: @JörgWMittag After checking more about scala, I think it's better not distinct the names `method` and `function` in the way you mentioned above. Just call it function for general, when it's a literal just call it function literal or anonymous function, when its a class member then could call it method. That's less confusing, and more compatible to other languages. From the online book `scala school` by Twitter, they also call it this way. It makes things much easier, and less confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return type in a function is actually the return type of the last expression that occurs in the function. In this case it's an `Int`, because `#length` returns an Int.

This is the work done by the compiler when it tries to infer the type. If you don't specify a type, it automatically gets inferred, but it's not necessarily `Unit`. You could force it to be that be stating it:

```scala
def wol(s: String): Unit = s.length.toString.length
```

**EDIT [syntactic sugar sample]**

I just remembered something that might be connected to your previous beliefs. When you define a method without specifying its return type and without putting the `=` sign, the compiler will force the return type to be Unit.

```scala
def wol(s: String) {
  s.length.toString.length
}

val x = wol("") // x has type Unit!
```

IntelliJ actually warns you and gives the hint `Useless expression`. Behind the scene, the `#wol` function here is converted into something like:

```scala
// This is actually the same as the first function
def wol(s: String): Unit = { s.length.toString.length }
```

Anyway, as a best practice try to avoid using this syntax and always opt for putting that `=` sign. Furthermore if you define public methods try to always specify the return type.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: According to your answer, I just tried this `def wol(x: Boolean) = { if (x) 1 else "hello" }` seems it's `wol: (x: Boolean)Any`. And this one `def wol(x: Boolean) = { if (x) 1 else 1.1 }` is `wol: (x: Boolean)Double`. So if there are multiple possible return types, the compiler will infer it to the smallest Super type for all possible return types?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how type inference works. Nice job figuring it out so fast :)

Comment: Yeah, that shows scala code is really neater than Java ones :)

Comment: Yup. I also encourage you to read more about scala expressions in general, you'll be quite amazed of their power

Comment: I am looking forward to find out that ;-)

Comment: @Eric Wang Check out the latest edit as well, I just remembered something.

Comment: Got that, nice tip.